# ExtJS 4, how to multi-select grid row as well as single row is also clickable?

Tags: extjs, checkbox, grid, extjs4.2

I am trying to create a grid using extjs 4.2.2. The grid contains several rows, if I click one row, then  pops up another page which displays the detail info of that row.
The grid is in a panel, so the view code is:

```
Ext.define("Application.view.foo.Panel", {
extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",
cls: 'foo.panel'
...
items: [
{
  itemId: "foo-bar",
  xtype: "grid",
  ...
  ,selType: 'checkboxmodel'
  ,columns: [
      xtype: 'templatecolumn'
```

and the code of listening row select event in controller is like:

```
"panel[cls~=foo.panel] #foo-bar": {
 select: function(selectionModel, record, index) { .... }
```

Now, I am going to add check box for each row in order to mass edit, I added `selType: 'checkboxmodel'`, but the problem is that I cannot click the check box: **if I click the box, it goes the the detail page, not just being 'checked', cuz the code in controller listens that 'row click' event.**

Is there any suggestions to implement it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: get rid of itemClick listener, add top or bottom toolbar add a button with text "edit", listen to click on that button on controller, get all selected/checked rows and do whatever is necessary

Comment: I want to click the single row to view details, and also, I want to select multiple rows to do edit.

Comment: put actionButtons, get rid of itemClick, add the button to the toolbar to mass edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to change your row click listener to view row details with action column.

```
{
        xtype:'actioncolumn',
        width:50,
        items: [{
            // Url is just for example (not working)
            icon: 'extjs/examples/shared/icons/fam/showDetails.png',  // Use a URL in the icon config
            tooltip: 'Show details',
            handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                // do your functionality here...
            }
}
```

In every row will appear an icon, and then you will have possibility to multiselect rows and to look details of every row as well. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to listen on cellclick event instead.

```
cellclick: function(view, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
   if(cellIndex != your_checkbox_column) {
      //do your info page stuff here    
   }
}
```

Comment: I am using grid.Panel, which does not support cellclick.